# Possible to save a snapshot from the current Crome Inspector display (Elements tab) to the clipboard or to a text file?

Tags: google-chrome, inspector

I am using Chrome's Inspector while development of automation code. Often I would like to take a 'snapshot' of the current display in the Inspector, for later reference. I have been just taking a screen shot, which is usually enough. But when the Inspector display exceeds the size of my display, the only way to see everything is to scroll.

I'm using Greenshot, and AFAIK, it doesn't support capturing everything in a scrollable window. Also, I don't think Chrome extensions operate inside the Inspector, so an extension that captures a scrolling page won't suffice.

What I'd like to do is a "Select All" of the entire Inspector (Elements tab) window, and then simply copy it to my clipboard. But the Inspector's right-click context menu does not have a Select All (or any of the usual cut/copy/paste choices either). Nor does Ctrl-A select anything.

Is there any solution to getting a screen shot or clipboard copy of the current state of an Inspector Elements tab?

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution for myself in **ShareX** (https://getsharex.com). It features, among many other things, a scrolling screen capture.

It also has OCR capturing if I really need the text, but for my immediate purposes the scrolling screen capture is more than enough :-)